# Having trouble connecting to mysql (xampp) with jdbc in a GWT app - class not found even though jar is in build path

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm attempting to connect to a MySQL database using JDBC. The MySQL database is running using XAMPP. The first thing I did was create a user in phpMyAdmin using this query:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';

GRANT SELECT , 
INSERT ,
UPDATE ,
DELETE ON * . * TO  'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0     MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `my_database` . * TO  'root'@'%';
```

I'm using GWT, so I then created a service in GWT and set it up correctly using web.xml. I've already confirmed that my app finds the service just fine and is attempting to connect to the db. I put mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar in both my project's war/WEB-INF/lib directory (and added it to the build path in Eclipse) and in Tomcat's lib folder, for good measure (I read somewhere that that might be necessary).

I'm trying to connect to my db using this code (the password and db name are correct, I've edited them here for privacy):

```
// import java.sql.*; is in the import statements

Connection db = null; 
System.out.println("Attempting to connect to database.");

String uid = "root"; 
String pwd = "my_password"; 
String db_name = "my_database"; 
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/" + db_name; 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uid, pwd); 
System.out.println("DB connection successful for database \"" + db_name + "\"");

Statement s = db.createStatement(); 
s.executeQuery("INSERT INTO `companies`(`name`) VALUES ('blahblah');");
```

When I run the app, it prints "Attempting to connect to database." but then prints, in red, "DB connection failed: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". When I check my db in phpMyAdmin, there is of course no 'blahblah' company added to the companies table.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the problem is. I would appreciate any help!

EDIT: I imported `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;` and the error message changed. Here is the new stack trace. I even specified the URL to include the port number like so: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + db_name;` but that didn't help.

```
Dec 03, 2012 5:19:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.Boolean com.candor.cougar.client.SqlService.connect()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:380)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.candor.cougar.server.SqlServiceImpl.connect(SqlServiceImpl.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
... 38 more

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:289)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver$1.<init>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:90)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:89)
... 47 more

Dec 03, 2012 5:19:28 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details

at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Regarding tags in title, the general consensus around here is that [they're not needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Please paste whole stacktrace. If you want to play around with SQL I'd suggest you using a library like [JDBI](http://jdbi.codehaus.org/) for convinience.

Comment: I edited my post to include the stacktrace. I'll look into JDBI, thanks. I'd still like to get this working though.

Comment: so, the driver jar is not in the classpath

Comment: I can't get JDBI working, for some reason the GWT plugin for Eclipse blocks it with an error saying that it doesn't work with GWT. I did make some small progress (I think) but now I'm getting more errors. Again, any help would be appreciated! I've been on this problem for days now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem is, so I thought I would answer my own question here. The problem was that Google App Engine was enabled by default since it was a GWT app, and GAE conflicts with database access. So, I disabled GAE in the project properties and removed all GAE-related .jars (which for me meant all of the .jars except for the mysql connector) from the Build Path, and it fixed the issue.